# Installing mysql cluster on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql-cluster

Mysql supposedly provides an APT repository for installing mysql cluster
*https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-cluster-install*

My understanding is that in order to use this repository I need to install the mysql-apt-config package, which I have done:

*sudo dpkg -i  mysql-apt-config_0.8.4-1_all.deb*

However when I try to run the command:

*sudo apt-get install mysql-cluster-community-server*

I get this error:

*E: Unable to locate package mysql-cluster-community-server*

Any ideas why I get this?

Also, has anyone else installed mysql cluster using any other methods that you can recommend?

Comment: I have the same issue.  It seems as though the cluster packages aren't included in the apt repo anymore?  Did you ever find a solution?